# Как сделать такую же ветку gh-pages?

Tags: git, github

Возможно я выражусь неправильно, но я попытаюсь обьяснить. У меня есть репозиторий в котором у меня лежат домашние задания в папка по такому пути:

```
homeworks/homework_1/index.html 
homeworks/homework_2/index.html
```

Я хочу создать отдельную ветку (gh-pages) как в этом профиле https://github.com/SvetlanaSharkunova/vanilla-js-miniprojects-FCC/tree/gh-pages
и в основной веткее (main) в readme.md указать ссылки на домашние работы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать?

Comment: В данном случае просто была создана новая ветка сразу после создания репозитория. Потом в main просто readme оставили, а в develop и gh-pages добавили разных папок. По сути ваш вопрос сводится к "как создать ветку с помощью git".

Comment: Спасибо, да все так и есть. Разобрался